# Connection refused by mongo server idk why

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo model like this:-

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const itemsModel = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
    },
    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    itemId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("itemsModel", itemsModel);
```

and I am handling my backend route in a file called `itemRoute.js` like this:-

````
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const id = require('uuid');
const itemsModel = require("../src/model/itemsModel");

router.post('/add-item/', (req, res) => {
    const { userName, description, itemId } = req.body;

    itemsModel.findOne({
        itemId: itemId,
        userName: userName,
    }, (error, prevData) => {
        if(error){
            return res.send({
                success: false,
                description: `Internal Server Error ${error}`
            });
        }
        
        if (prevData.length > 0){
            itemsModel.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: prevData[0]._id }, 
                { description: description },
                (error, status) => {
                    if (error){
                        return res.json({
                            success: false,
                            description: `Internal Server Error ${error}`
                        });
                    } else {
                        return res.status(200).json({
                            success: true,
                            description: "Updated item successfully",
                            prevData: prevData,
                            status: status
                        });
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        const newModel = new itemsModel;
        newModel._id = id.v4();
        newModel.userName = userName;
        newModel.itemId = itemId;
        newModel.description = description;

        newModel.save((error, user) => {
            if(error){
                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    description: `Internal Server Error ${error}`
                });
            }

            return res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                description: "Added item to db",
                user: user
            });
        });
    });
});

router.get('/get-items/:itemId/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const itemId = req.params.itemId;

    return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        description: "Nicee",
        id: itemId,
    });
});

module.exports = router;```
````

I have the following in my `index.js` express file:-
`app.use('/api', require('./routes/itemRoute'));`
and I am calling from my frontend like this:-

```
handleAddItemButton = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      userName: this.props.userName,
      description: this.state.description,
      itemId: this.props.itemId,
    }

    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/add-item/`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

My `index.js` file:-

```
/* jshint esversion:6 */
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static('./build'));
app.use(express.static('./build/static'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/items'));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/itemRoute'));
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

const port = 8000

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/item-app', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
})

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'))
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server running at ${port}`));
```

When my frontend actually makes the request, I am thrown the following error:-
`POST http://localhost:8000/api/add-item/  net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
I have looked through my code again and again but to no avail. Any and all help is sincerely appreciated. Please guide me through what Im doing wrong.

Edit 1:-
After @ewokx comment I ran mongod and got the following;-
[image]
Is this the issue? How to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right port?  is mongod running?

Comment: yes everything is running. Backend is running on port 8000, react running on 3000 and i Can connect to mongo using compass as well.

Comment: How did you run compass against mongo?  Is mongo listening to all interfaces or just the external one?

Comment: no need to run mongodb compass you have to connect your backend with mongodb can you show your db connection string

Comment: @AmirShahzad can you tell me how do i get that?

Comment: @ewokx I used compass to connect to 127.0.0.1 and its now showing me all the mongo models in my backend so im assuming its working

Comment: yes your compass is running but did you create a connection your app to mongodb???

Comment: i dont think I have done that. I have edited the question a bit as well at the last part. Please check that too once.

Comment: show your app.js file code where you conncted your application with mongodb?

Comment: @PTTX: **Danger!** the last code snippet you posted includes the mongo database credentials for a cloud DB instance.  You should rotate those credentials immediately, and be more careful with copy & paste in the future.

Comment: Yes, i just saw that! No worries tho, coz it was an expired instance and the ips keep changing every 30 mins. But yeah, thanks a lot for the heads up! Have edited it out

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB requires a data folder to store its files.
The default location for the MongoDB data directory is `c:\data\db`. So, create this folder it will solve your issue.

Comment: it is already there but now showing in mongod idk why

Comment: that means the folder that you created does not have the correct permissions. So, grant permissions to the `c:/data/db` directory using `chmod` command

Comment: data/db is working but that doesnt seem to have solved my problem

Comment: Did you check the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Hi so I seem to have successfully solved the problem. The problem wasn't with any of the things like db permissions, mongod, ports or something like that. I reset my `index.js` file to match the db name in the db connection.
Another thing I was doing wrong, I was passing a json stringified object as the request body. Removing that and on connecting proeprly to the db, the code started working nicely.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).